# Wrap Text with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to code the wrap text function with FPDF, but I keep on geting the "HTTP ERROR 500" and can't find why. Can somebody help me? Here is the snipett:

```
require ('C:\Users\mcane\scoop\apps\apache\2.4.43\htdocs\PHP\vendor\fpdf\fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm', 'A4');
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
//define standard font size
$fontsize=12;

$pdf->Cell(150,5,"Multicell Method",0,1);
```

($data2 is an array of 3 arrays, each one with text input distributed inn four rows)

```
foreach($data2 as $item){
    $cellWidth=80; //wrapped cell width
    $cellHeight=5; //normal one-line cell height
```

check wether the text is overflowing

```
if($pdf->getStringWidth($item[2]) < $cellWidth){
    //if not then do nothing 
    $line=1;
}else{
```

if it is then calculate the height needed for wrapped cell
by splitting the text to fit the cell witdth
then count how many lines are needed for the text to fit the cell

```
    $textLenght=strlen($item[2]); //total text lenght
    $errmargin=10; //cell width error margin
    $startChar=0; // character start position for each line
    $maxChar=0; // max char in a line to be incremented later
    $textArray=array(); // to hold the strings for each line
    $tmpString=""; // to hold the string for a line (temporary)
    
    while($startChar < $textLenght){ // loop until end of the text
```

loop until maximum character reached

```
        while( 
            §pdf->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errmargin) &&
            ($startChar+$maxChar) < ( $textLenght ) ) {
                $maxChar++;
                $tmpString= ($item[2], $startChar, $maxChar);
            }
            // move startChar to next line
            $startChar=$startChar+$maxChar;
            //then add it into the array so we know how many line are needed
            array_push($textArray,$tmpString);
            //reset maxChar and tmpString
            $maxChar=0;
            $tmpString='';                  
    }
```

get the number of lines

```
    $line=count($textArray);
}
```

write the cells

```
$pdf->Cell(10,($line * $cellHeight),$item[0],1,0); // adapt height to number of lines
$pdf->Cell(60,($line * $cellHeight),$item[1],1,0); // adapt height to number of lines
```

use Multicell instead of Cell
but first, because Multicell is always treated as line ending, we need to
manually set the xy position for the next cell to be next to it
remember the x and y position befor writing the multicell

```
$xPos=$pdf->GetX();
$yPos=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->Multicell($cellWidth, $cellHeight,$item[2],1);
```

return the position for next cell next to q the multicell
and offset x with Multicell width

```
$pdf->SetXY($xPos + $cellWidth, $yPos);



$pdf->Cell(40,($line * $cellHeight),$item[3],1,1); // adapt height to number of lines   
        

}

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Check you servers log file. Details on what caused the 500 error will be there.

Comment: It says "[php7:error] [pid 13572:tid 1220] [client ::1:54533] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in C:\\Users\\mcane\\scoop\\persist\\apache\\htdocs\\Katdancing\\textwrap.php on line 66.." This is line 66: §pdf->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errmargin) &&

Comment: As expected the error points you to exactly where the problem is in your code (textwrap.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the error: **§pdf**->GetStringWidth( $tmpString ) < ($cellWidth-$errmargin) &&